# What is the folder where the images need to be for mass importing products?

Tags: magento2, product-images, import, import-products

What is the folder where the images need to be for mass importing products ?
I seen there in import admin panel that is var/import/images/products_images but no is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default location is 
var/import/images

and do not include the path before the filename in the CSV data.

> Starting with the Magento 2.3.2 release, the path specified in the
>   Images File Directory concatenates for import to the images base
>   directory - /var/import/images. For earlier
>   Magento releases, you can use a different folder on the Magento
>   server, as long as the path to the folder is specified during the
>   import process.

Ref:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html

Comment: why it writes /var/import/images/products_images ?

Comment: Just try to import one with magento/var/import/images/ Test and play with one.

Comment: i see the directory don't exist should i create it ? # cd import
-bash: cd: import: No such file or directory
and if yes what permissions should i give to it ? chmod 777 ?

Comment: Yes you can, remember var in Magento directory